# Autostart android service

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

How to automatically start a service in Android 3.x, the test tabblet is a Samsung Galaxy 10.1. My code works on a noname tabblet with android 2.2.1 The code works nor in android emulator with the android version 3.x

Code:

StartAtBootService.java
    package test.autostart;

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class StartAtBootService extends Service 
{
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() 
        {
            Log.v("StartServiceAtBoot", "onCreate");
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
        {
            Log.v("StartServiceAtBoot", "onStartCommand()");          
            return START_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() 
        {
            Log.v("StartServiceAtBoot", "onDestroy");
        }
}
```

StartAtBootServiceReciver.java
    package test.autostart;

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class StartAtBootServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction("test.autostart.StartAtBootService");
            context.startService(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <service android:name="StartAtBootService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="test.autostart.StartAtBootService">
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="StartAtBootServiceReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
                </action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME">
                </category>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: do you not get the onReceive call on boot?

Answer (score 5):

It was a SD-card issue, Eclipse install new apps on the SD-card by default on my Samsung Galaxy 10.1. To fix the issue I needed to add android:installLocation="internalOnly" in the manifest.

The new Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="test.autostart"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="internalOnly">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <service android:name="StartAtBootService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="test.autostart.StartAtBootService">
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="StartAtBootServiceReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
                </action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME">
                </category>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I hope this will help somone in the futre.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your application is not on SD. I your application needs to run on boot time, then do not place it on SD.

Comment: if he runs it on the emulator i suppose there's no SD involved anyway

Comment: I use eclpise to install it and testing, with both emulator, galaxy 10.1 and a noname tabblet with android 2.2.1. and my code only works with android 2.2.1.

Comment: Yes, Android SDK emulators do have SD.
@OP: did you make sure the app on emulator is not on SD?

Comment: Emulators actually have problems of being different from actual devices for some reason. I've had problems running some apps on 2.3.3 emulator while it works perfectly on my actual 2.3.3 device.