# Android InstallLocation

Tags: android, android-manifest

I would like to know which one is good when we put the app in google play

1. Having android:installLocation="preferExternal" or
2. Without mentioning anything on the location

In the following statement, whats is the difference between the versionCode and versionName

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Isn't the install location usually up to the user? Also I think versionCode is used internally whereas versionName is what's displayed on the store

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you declare "preferExternal", you request that your application be installed on the external storage, but the system does not guarantee that your application will be installed on the external storage. If the external storage is full, the system will install it on the internal storage. The user can also move your application between the two locations.

If you declare "auto", you indicate that your application may be installed on the external storage, but you don't have a preference of install location. The system will decide where to install your application based on several factors. The user can also move your application between the two locations.

```
android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="0.5.02"
```

Comment: is it possible to move the apk from internal to external storage from sdk version 23 onwards?because Im not getting the option for it.I think permission is removed from the android os iteslf.please help

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the Android Api Guide,

> Beginning with API Level 8, you can allow your application to be
>   installed on the external storage (for example, the device's SD card).
>   This is an optional feature you can declare for your application with
>   the android:installLocation manifest attribute. If you do not declare
>   this attribute, your application will be installed on the internal
>   storage only and it cannot be moved to the external storage.

I believe It is better to declare `android:installLocation` because,

1. Internal Storage is limited in some devices.
2. user has the option to move the application between Internal and External Storage.

See [Android API Guide on App Install Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html) for  more information in this regard.

[this](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html) will answer your question about `android:versionCode` and `android:versionName`

Hope that helps!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: do we have any advantage in using internal when compared to the external staorage

Comment: See I have edited my answer. Take a look at the new link provided in my answer. There are situations where it is not good to install the app in external storage.

Answer (score 1):

versionCode — An integer value that represents the version of the application
  code, relative to other versions.
versionName — A string value that represents the release version of the
  application code, as it should be shown to users.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know which one is good when we put the app in google play

It depends on your app requirement.

As i am working on a [**sleep Cycle app**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lslk.sleepbot) like this. Where we need a service to run all night without stopping. If you put your app on SDCard using `preferExternal` . As soon as the user unmount the external storage, the process in which these things run will be terminated.

In this situation I must set `android:installLocation="internalOnly"`

And when you put your app in `external storage`. It will not [recieve system broadcast.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344897/autostart-android-service)